# Launch a docker container in an unit test

Tags: c#, .net, docker, azure-cosmosdb

In order to have in-memory test, I would like to launch the [azure-cosmosdb-emulator](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator) docker container at the beginning of my test, send the connection data to my repository and insert data in my container.

Following [this doc](https://www.meziantou.net/integration-testing-using-a-docker-container.htm) and [this one](http://www.arolla.fr/blog/2019/05/tester-repository-azure-cosmos-db/), I provided the following code :

```
namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            using (var conf = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("https://registry-1.docker.io")))
            using (var client = conf.CreateClient())
            {
                await client.Images.CreateImageAsync(new ImagesCreateParameters()
                {
                    FromImage = "azure-cosmosdb-emulator:latest",
                    Repo = "azure-cosmosdb-emulator",
                    Tag = "latest",
                    FromSrc = "https://registry-1.docker.io"
                }, null, new Progress());

            }
        }
    }

    public class Progress : IProgress<JSONMessage>
    {
        public void Report(JSONMessage value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly I have the following error message :

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Connection failed
>   ---- System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException : Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu. [::ffff:54.210.105.17]:443

I'm not sure the `https://registry-1.docker.io` URL is good. What do you think about ?
If it's not this, is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Uri you are using for the `DockerClientConfiguration` object is incorrect. It should be the Uri to the remote docker host like `tcp://<remote-host>:<remote-port>` **or** you can simply use `new DockerClientConfiguration()` which uses the default local socket.

You can read more about this in the [README for the .NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/Docker.DotNet#usage).